# Dold-Thom stabilization and the inverse map on the homology.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Consider the closed immersion of complex varieties $i:\text{Sym}^n(\mathbb{P}^d_{\mathbb{C}})\hookrightarrow \text{Sym}^{n+1}(\mathbb{P}^d_{\mathbb{C}})$ induced by adding a fixed point. Let $Z$ be closed subvariety of $\text{Sym}^n(\mathbb{P}^{d+1}_{\mathbb{C}})$ where $\text{dim}(Z)<< \text{dim}(\text{Sym}^n(\mathbb{P}^d_{\mathbb{C}}))$. Is it possible to find a continuous (not regular necessarily) map $f: Z \rightarrow \text{Sym}^n(\mathbb{P}^d_{\mathbb{C}})$, such that $f$ is identity on the intersection of $Z$ and $\text{Sym}^n(\mathbb{P}^d_{\mathbb{C}})$?

The reason why I thought there might be a map, comes from the Dold-Thom theorem, which implies that $i$-th homology of symmetric power eventually stabilizes. I was thinking whether it is possible to give a map on the homology (after the stabilization) in the wrong direction i.e. from the homology of $\text{Sym}^n(\mathbb{P}^{d+1}_{\mathbb{C}})$ to the homology $\text{Sym}^n(\mathbb{P}^d_{\mathbb{C}})$. This map is supposed to be the inverse of the map on the homology induced by the inclusion. By Lefschetz hyperplane theorem we know that the $i$-th homology of $\text{Sym}^n(\mathbb{P}^{d+1}_{\mathbb{C}})$ is supported on a subvariety $Z$. More precisely they have the same homology. Now if the statement in my question is correct then one can get the inverse map on the homology.